# Only able to log in to my local WordPress site's back end by visiting the front end first?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, wamp, frontend, backend

This is a weird problem that I'm trying to figure out.  I use WAMP to build WordPress sites locally.  All of my sites work fine except the main one I am working on now.  I am using Chrome on Windows 7 but it happens on any browser.  Basically all of the sudden when i go to `localhost/mysite/wp-admin` the login screen comes up and when I type in my username and password and hit enter it's basically like the page refreshes and my login info has to be reentered.  This will repeat infinity for the most part.  First time this happened it took about 10 tries and then it logged in.  It still happens daily and I found somewhat of a weird solution.  Basically I have to go to the sites front end `localhost/mysite/` and load that up.  Once it's up I then add `/wp-admin` to the URL, hit enter and when I login again it usually works.  Not 100% but this has been the only way to log on as of now.  Anyone experience this?  Like I said all my other sites do not have this problem.  What can be causing this?  A plugin perhaps?  It's just a weird problem and I don't like the solution I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i kinda remember having a similar problem, the problem was for me my wp installation had trouble with the database and i backed up everything and fresh installed everything. i hope this one works for you

Comment: Any best practices for backing up everything?  I used to use Joomla but kind of new to WordPress.

Comment: look for wp backup plug in there are plenty of them around there